# Gitolite ACL partition activation with fstab ?

Tags: git, acl, gitolite, gitosis, hadoop-partitioning

I don't understand and i don't find any information about ACL and gitolite.

In first intention, i want to install gitosis, which need instalation of `apt-get install ACL package` for debian, and activation of **acl** into **fstab** file.

With gitolite, a great fork of gitosis, i don't find any information about this step, can you enlight me on this point ?

Thanks,
SR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gitosis (which is completely obsolete, and [not updated since 2009](http://eagain.net/gitweb/?p=gitosis.git)) doesn't reference any *system* ACL, because it defines its own ACL management.

For [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), the [documentation](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/master-toc.html#index) describes the access control as [declared in `gitolite.conf`](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/conf.html).

> Gitolite has an advanced access control language that is designed to be powerful but easy to use.
>   Other objectives were that it should be even easier to read, review and audit the rules, and it should scale to thousands of repos and users.

So the ACL is an applicative one based on a declaration in a file, rather than a system one.